# Using regular expressions or pattern matching inside method calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am using the testing the mechanical soup package to get into some webscraping stuff and I came across an interesting problem. I want to get a list of all the links in a page that have a period in the displayed text, indicating a file. I can check for that using an if statement inside a for loop:

```
for link in browser.links():
     if '.' in str(link.string):
```

But the links method has a way to search the string of a link by using link_text="whatever", but it needs to match exactly.

Is there any way I can do:

```
for link in browser.links(link_text=something_with_a_period_in_it):
```

I have a feeling this won't save any computation time but I can see it being useful in the future.

Comment: provide a sample html to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it if you override the equality comparison.**

The [code](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/blob/master/mechanicalsoup/stateful_browser.py#L208) for the `links()` method shows that this is all that's being done with `link_text`:

```
if link_text is not None:
    all_links = [a for a in all_links 
                 if a.text == link_text]
```

So it's just a simple equality comparison. What you want is an object that compares equal to a string if and only if that string contains a `.`. Here's a simple example:

```
class ContainsDot(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return '.' in other
```

You'll need to instantiate it, then you can compare it to any string and get what you expect:

```
>>> c = ContainsDot()
>>> 'sdfsdfasdf' == c
False
>>> 'sdfasdf.asdfasd' == c
True
>>> c == 'sdfasdfa.asdfasd'
True
>>> c == ''
False
>>> c == '.'
True
```

I don't have MechanicalSoup and can't test, but it should be as simple as:

```
for link in browser.links(link_text=ContainsDot()):
```